# Get prototype method

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

I have a problem.
My code:

```
function Param(){
  this.name = 'sasha'
  this.method = function(){
    return this.name + 'native method'
  }
  this.pro= function(){
 debugger
  // Param.prototype.method() //undefined proto method bad!!
 //  this.__proto__.method() //undefinedproto method 
 Object.getPrototypeOf(this).method()  //undefinedproto method 
  }
}
Param.prototype.method = function(){
    console.log(this.name + 'proto method')
  }
 var param= new Param; 
 param.pro()
```

Help get the method prototype  with this.name = 'sasha' ...
He works like this  `Object.getPrototypeOf(this).method.call(this);`

Perhaps there is an alternative?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very simple solution: `this.method()`. That's just polymorphism.

If you want to be sure that you use a method from the prototype, you have to get it explicitly (through any of the 3 ways that you've shown), but then you also need to explicitly invoke it on the current instance by using `.call(this)`. There's nothing wrong with that.

If you want to define a `pro` method that does exactly what the `.prototype.method` does, you can simply directly assign it:

```
this.pro = Param.prototyp.method();
```

then `param.pro()` will invoke that prototype method on the instance with the name as well.